# Ion-slide when add html element form go down

Tags: angular, ionic2

i'm using form wizard using ion-slide, i controlled all the issues that i faced, like calling update() when add html element or ionic element, and the height of the slide , next , previous etcc,
i have put a message to appear when a ion-input is invalid and dirty , on many fields, so if the user write something error or invalid the message appear , or if the user click submit or next button and the form is invalid the message appear on all fields,
so when the messages appear, the form damaged, and some fields not appeared . also when the messages hide, the form not look good.
any one know how to fix it.
should i call the update function on each input change, i think it's not good practise.